# Installing a certificate emitted by Comodo on Apache Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, ssl

I have followed steps outlined in [Comodo Knowledge Base](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=1203&nav=0,96,1,95)

Edited my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and `/etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf` by adding

```
<VirtualHost 197.***.**.**:443>
     SSLEngine On
     SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/crt/www_mydomain_com.crt
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/key/www_mydomain_com.key
     SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/crt/www_mydomain_com.ca-bundle

     ServerAdmin info@mydomain.com
     ServerName www.mydomain.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/
     ErrorLog   /var/www/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I also have LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so
I tested for HTTS using  `telnet www.mydomain.com https` but its not working.
Error is `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out`

Could someone kindly point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to define the server port in the VirtualHost statement.

Don't forget to fully test your ssl configuration, for example with this checker https://sslcheck.globalsign.com/

Comment: Changed. Did a few tweaks and now am getting Unknown (No secure protocols supported). It's not finding my certificates